# ProOne 440 G5 does not work with Linux

Tags: 20.04, hp, fedora

We are trying to get Fedora 32 working on the ProOne 440 G5. We've also tested Ubuntu 20.04.1, but none of the distros seem to work at all. The screen just cycles through RGB, white and black on boot. It looks 90% similar to this:

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems-and-Recovery/Screen-Flashing-Different-Lights-While-Installing-a/m-p/7699504/highlight/true#M181634

Linux will boot with the kernel mode setting (KMS) disabled (`nomodeset`), but this disables the GPU driver and dramatically decreases video performance as well as lowering the resolution and disabling the sound. We need sound for our use-case.

Does anybody know how to get Fedora 32 or Ubuntu 20.04 working on this machine (or Linux in general)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The Image says "image" and nothing else. Note that Fedora is off topic on this site.

Comment: Sorry about that, the link must have changed or something... I know that I mentioned Fedora, but the problem seems to appear with Ubuntu as well. I am hoping that tackling the problem for Ubuntu will allow us to use the same fix for the problem with Fedora.